# How to start an activity or dialog, out of my application which don't stop current activity

Tags: java, android, dialog

I searched too much about opening a dialog from a service or broadcast receiver, and there is no answer, but i see opening a dialog via broadcast receiver in this app:

[image: this application is Fine Volume Control]

this app is an audio manager which you can change volumes and set profiles as soon as android volume changed (for this we should register a broadcast receiver with VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION action)
the interesting point for this app, is that it open's a dialog, not a themed activity or transparent activity, it seem that open a dialog, because this pop up don't stop current activity and treat like volume seek bar when you click volume up and down keys.
all of back environment are clickable!!

here is my app that use transparent activity:

[image: this app will called 2D Volume+]

when i open my dialog, it's stop current activity(for example, stop the game, while in game called) , and in many cases, it open a bit slower than Fine Volume Control app, it's appeared fast and close fast, and finally make the back environment dark(but Fine volume control doesn't make background dark)

summary:
how can I open a dialog in everywhere like this app [Fine Volume Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=opotech.finevolumev2&hl=en) which don't stop current activity?

Comment: These might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650463/getting-window-display-from-service-android

Comment: yes, thank you, the second link helped me :) i wondering, why we can make a view like dialog and with better performance, no body said this, and everybody tell this is impossible, but it is possible :)