# Display Alertbox from service

Tags: android

Is there any way to use alertbox in service rather then making another activity for it and then starting that activity from service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Service cannot show a `Dialog` , only you can show short lived `Toast` from there.

But If your Requirement is of showing dialog I will not disappoint you .You have got following options:

1. If you have a `MainActivity` use a `LocalBroadcastReceiver` to send a broadcast to your activity and let your MainActivity show a Dialog. (This will be possible only when your activity is visible)
2. The other option is Define a Dialog theme activity (take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1979631)) in your manifest and start that activity from service.
3. Another option could be , Define a Activitiy in Manifest whose sole purpose would be display a Dialog and start that activity from service

**Edit**

I have a suggestion , If you wish to present information to your users , you should use [Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) . The main reason that you cannot show a dialog from service is that Google wants information to be decently presented to its users , instead of surprising them when suppose they are in middle of a call , or typing message etc.

if the user is interested, then he will touch the notification and you start your own activity, possibly resuming your activity, creating a new one, and then using a dialog requesting action to be performed, or whatever you want to do.

**Alternative Solution**

However If you persist I have [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12650670/2319390) if you like hacking, (but I don't like hacks in good application).

Comment: Is there any other way to show alert box from service instead of making activities.

Comment: I have added a suggestion note and possible answer to your question :) enjoy

Comment: well my service checks if user is launching a certain application  then an alert dialog should appear asking for password. For this i need to declare alert box in service or from broadcast rather then making another activity.

Comment: well in that case you should definitely go with my above alternative solution , Which makes use of window manager , try to google about window manager example , and you will be satisfied :) .After implementing If you found it useful don't forget to accept answer ;)

Comment: its working to some extent.now m trying to make alertbox activity from it.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a custom Broadcast Receiver**

```
 public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

// AlertDialogue will be here

}

}
```

**Register it in the manifest file**

```
 <receiver android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sample.A_CUSTOM_INTENT">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

**Trigger the BroadcastReceiver from service**

```
   Intent intent = new Intent("MyCustomIntent");    
   EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.extraIntent);
   // add data to the Intent
   intent.putExtra("message", (CharSequence)et.getText().toString());
   intent.setAction("com.sample.A_CUSTOM_INTENT");
   sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: broadcast does not allow alertdialog i guess.

Comment: onReceive() is running on main (UI) thread.Then whats the problem ?Have you tried it? .

Comment: yp I have tried it .It just crashes the application.And my logcat does not show logs from  when app is running on cell phone

Comment: Try to trace the exception